# Why is everything lit by default?

Tags: lighting, unity

I am following the unity tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/environment) and when i drag my environment into the Hierarchy everything i already lit up on my Game view, i noticed this was also the case in the Space Shooter tutorial that i followed before this but i ignored it. Does Unity5 automatically light up things for you if you don't have any lights? I tried setting the ambient Intensity to zero but it literally changes nothing. When i drag in the lighting prefab it also doesn't seem to do much because the scene was already lit up somewhat.

It is still dark but it isn't pitch black like it should be in the Game view.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the global illumination that will be set up by default for all your objects to receive ambient/reflections from the skybox. Click the Window -> lighting. I won't go into detail as the official tutorial will explain everything:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/unity-5/unity5-lighting-overview

Cheers.